# INSERT function

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert values into DB, but I am getting an Error. When I add them one by one they work but if I want to add all of them this is the error I am getting:

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "blse_pkey"
> DETAIL:  Key (date, employment_1000s, industry, state)=(2020-01-31, 2082.7, Total Nonfarm                                     , Alabama) already exists.
> SQL state: 23505

This is the script I am using.

```sql
INSERT INTO blse VALUES('2020-01-31',436.5,'Government','Missouri'); 
INSERT INTO blse VALUES('2020-01-31',488.6,'Total Nonfarm','Montana');
```

Comment: The error states that you are trying to insert data that is duplicated `2020-01-31, 2082.7, Total Nonfarm , Alabama` these values are already in the database

Comment: Even when I use the following script I'm still getting the same error
INSERT INTO blse(date,employment_1000s,industry,state) VALUES('2020-01-31',291.5,'Manufacturing','Washington');

Comment: Then those values exist already as well. Have you looked at the DDL for the table that tells you what the constraints are? Have you looked at the existing data in the table to see what values exist already?

Comment: can you please show us the create table blse, maybe the date is unique or primary key

Comment: @nbk: Clearly it's a unique constraint issue - the error message says exactly that, very clearly. See **duplicate key value violates unique constraint** in the message text.